# htaccess rewrite stopped working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been using the following rewrite rule in my htaccess file:
`RewriteRule ^/UA/ - [L]`

In order to pass through requests to a specific folder, everything else goes to index.php.

Today it stopped working! The only thing I have (intentionally) changed is the DB I am using which I renamed and changed the password for, I can't see how this would affect the redirects.

My full htaccess file looks like this, please, can anyone see why the above redirect is no longer working?

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

#Allow UA access
RewriteRule ^/UA/ - [L]

#Allow certain file types to access directly
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg|ico)$ - [L]

# Catch all
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

EDIT: -----
I have cleaned up my original file from above as there was an irrelevant redirect contain within it, I have then added some changes suggested by @anubhava so that I have the following:

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

#Allow UA access
RewriteRule ^/?UA/ - [L,NC]

#Allow certain file types to access directly
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg|ico)$ - [L,NC]

# Catch all
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

But this is still not redirecting successfully.  I have this htaccess file in my www root with an additional one in the UA folder to pick up any redirects into it.
A request to `www.mydomain.com/UA` is returning `www.mydomain.com/index.php` rather than `www.mydomain.com/UA/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# Redirect to HTTPS site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#Allow UA access
RewriteRule ^/?UA/ - [L,NC]

#Allow certain file types to access directly
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg|ico)$ - [L,NC]

# Catch all
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```